# Native module cannot be null, but the app works fine

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

`react-native run-ios` successfully builds the project and the app is started at simulator, however, I got the error below, I tried to get more details in the Xcode log, I only got this:

```
[fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.
```

How can I debug this error? is it just a warning? I can see fatal in Xcode log.

If I press on Dismiss in simulator, the error below gone and the app seems to work fine..

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Check this thread https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2977. It seems related to your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I have manually linked RCTLinking and the problem is solved :)